# Getting the value of nested xml with same node names in xml using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am a newbee to Groovy, am trying to print the below output using Groovy but I was unable to fetch the Zone values from the below XML.

I try to use .each and save the offercode into a list and print the values but I could not able to do the same with Zone. Could you please guide me on this.

Here is XML:

```html
          <ns8:Offers>
            <ns8:Offer>
               <ns8:offerDetails>
                  <offerCode>6789</offerCode>
                  <offerCategory>ABCED</offerCategory>
                  <offerType>
                     <Value>Promo</Value>
                     <Language>E</Language>     
               </ns8:offerDetails>
               <ns8:offerZones>
                  <ns8:zone>Zone 1</ns8:zone>
                  <ns8:zone>Zone 2</ns8:zone>
                  <ns8:zone>Zone 3</ns8:zone>
                  <ns8:zone>Zone 4</ns8:zone>
               </ns8:offerZones>
            </ns8:Offer>
            <ns8:Offer>
               <ns8:offerDetails>
                  <offerCode>12345</offerCode>
                  <offerCategory>ABCED</offerCategory>
                  <offerType>
                     <Value>Promo</Value>
                     <Language>E</Language>     
               </ns8:offerDetails>
               <ns8:offerZones>
                  <ns8:zone>Zone 1</ns8:zone>
                  <ns8:zone>Zone 2</ns8:zone>
                  <ns8:zone>Zone 3</ns8:zone>
                  <ns8:zone>Zone 4</ns8:zone>
               </ns8:offerZones>
            </ns8:Offer>
             <ns8:Offer>
               <ns8:offerDetails>
                  <offerCode>12345</offerCode>
                  <offerCategory>ABCED</offerCategory>
                  <offerType>
                     <Value>Promo</Value>
                     <Language>E</Language>     
               </ns8:offerDetails>
            </ns8:Offer>
         </ns8:Offers>
```

Expected Output: `Offer code is :6789 and Offer Zone are:Zone 1,Zone 2,Zone 3,Zone 4`

```js
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder


def QuerySubscriberResponse = context.expand( '${QuerySubscriber#Response}' )
def queryxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(QuerySubscriberResponse)

def nbaofferscode=[];

                def nbaOffersZone=[];
                queryxml.Body.querySubscriberResponse.profferOffers.profferOffer.each{ nbaofferss ->

                  nbaofferscode.add(nbaofferss.offerDetails.offerCode)
                    

                }

log.info  nbaofferscode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your example.

1. The XML is invalid: all the `<ns8:offerDetails>` elements have missing closing tags.
2. Your GPath doesn't match the XML.

It looks like your GPath is expecting the XML to be embedded in a web page.

In this example I've added the missing `</ns8:offerDetails>` closing tags and loaded the XML from a file.

```
file = new File( 'NestedXml.xml')
def queryxml = new XmlParser(false,false)
  .parse( file )

def nbaofferscode=[];
def nbaOffersZone=[];

queryxml.each { offer ->
  offer.'ns8:offerZones'.'ns8:zone'.each { zone ->
    nbaOffersZone << zone.text()
  }
  nbaofferscode << offer.'ns8:offerDetails'.offerCode.text()
}

println nbaofferscode
println nbaOffersZone
```

Running the above script gives this output:

```
[6789, 12345, 12345]
[Zone 1, Zone 2, Zone 3, Zone 4, Zone 1, Zone 2, Zone 3, Zone 4]
```

The third offer doesn't contain any zones.